# "ubuntu the partition table format in your disks normally requires" on ubuntu installation

Tags: 16.04, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I dont have windows. I have only one ubuntu.

I want to reinstall it. I come to installation and select "seomething else" described here
https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-with-screenshots/

after clicking start installation,

it says this

```
ubuntu the partition table format in your disks normally requires you to create a seperate partition
```

Secure boot is not enabled.  and legacy mode is not enabled or force legacy mode is not enabled.

After clicking ok, it says

> If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult
>   to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later. If
>   you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the
>   ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to
>   force that here

Whhy is it keeping saying this?

I am installing from usb.

it is 16.04.

laptop is

Dell Latitude 5000

in past, i had windows but i removed it.

Should i contiune despite those 2 warnings? In future something happens?

**update**

i continued and after restart, there is mnothing to boot from it says. cant find

maybe i should first go with live usb and format ?

because it is new install, i can reinstall again but i dont want to have those problems again.

Comment: You can continue as you only want to install Ubuntu. You should care that warning if you want to have dual boot.

Comment: I continued and it restarted with my permisson. i took of usb and now it cant boot. it says no bootable devices found

Comment: Ok. What is your boot mode in BIOS? and what is your Disk Partition Type? MBR or GPT?

Comment: Mode is uefi. i made all parts ext4 whle installing but i dont know how to loook. i cant login to tty. Should i go to live usb try without installing?

Comment: Ok, Can you explain about the partitions you made and the Mounting Points?

Comment: @PRATAP i followed that tutorial. same  as it https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-with-screenshots/ only for /home i made 60 gb. i am on live usb. i wrote df -T it shows a lot of parts, most of them are tmpfs, one aufs, one squashfs, one vfat

Comment: have you created EFI partition or not? you must have to Create EFI Partition first before doing other partitions as you booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: first you change the Boot Mode to BIOS and see if the system is taking you to Ubuntu. Later we will discuss about this EFI Partition.

Comment: I enabled legacy options and could not see again ubuntu too. Bİos mode is legacy mode? to create efi partition is not that? https://www.linuxtechi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/new-partition-table-ubuntu-installation.jpg

Comment: Hi, go back with UEFI and then go to something else screen and can you send me that pic. after taking that pic go back and select try ubuntu option and open Gparted.

Comment: I did. i am sending 3 photos. for gparted, something else, and before something else @PRATAP photos.app.goo.gl/EHBr9FQTJ2MezxFp9 photos.app.goo.gl/xH32PRbSoV1v34KS6 photos.app.goo.gl/j9nZ6ov7BHvSdpms5 there is no windows. it was weeks ago. i deleted it and after that i reinstalled ubuntu 3 times. it goes login boot and cant fix it  this is from insatlled ub ubuntu https://photos.app.goo.gl/fRtHayVBFqe7v8Ry7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep Boot mode in BIOS with "UEFI mode"
go with the "Install Ubuntu" Option.
Choose Something Else option.

1. Create a EFI Partition of around 500mb
2. Create a EXT4 Partition of your wish (100gb or 200gb) for installing Ubuntu and Mount it to / (Slash)
3. If you want to use swap partition, create a swap partition with 2 times of your RAM.
4. If you want to give additional space for home folder create a EXT4 partition of your wish and mount it to /home.
5. leave the remaining place unallocated as you can make them after installation.
6. select the device for boot loader from the drop down option at bottom of the window as `/dev/sdX` (X is a variable) replace X with your intended drive. if you have two drives they may be named sda and sdb. this is very important. and click "Install Now"
   Note: steps 3 & 4 are not mandatory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78707/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-ubuntu-the-partition-table-format-in-your-disks).

Comment: I cant login again :( this is fifth time

Comment: I installes yakuake chrome zsh notepadqq steam foxitreader and restartrd only.