# How do I prevent a second install of Ubuntu from modifying GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

I have one hard drive with my main Linux Mint install. I have a second hard drive in my system. I then installed Ubuntu on the second hard drive. My motherboard is UEFI.

I assumed that these OS partitions on separate drives would not influence each other. I thought I could just load to my bios boot menu, and select the drive I want. My assumptions were incorrect.

When I installed the second Ubuntu, it manipulated GRUB (which I understand very little about). I then formatted the drive with Ubuntu on it, and my grub is now corrupt because it points to an unknown partition. **Just to be clear, my question is not about how to fix my currently broken GRUB.**

My question is, how can I install different Ubuntu flavours on my second hard drive, without it in any way jeopardising whether my main primary OS drive will correctly boot?

I would just like to be able to tell my motherboard which device to boot from, and then have it boot from that, I don't want the second drive somehow breaking the boot of the first drive.

Comment: while installing OS on other drive, create a EFI system partition on it and choose "bootloader for installation" the same drive. this will still grab the entry of OS on primary drive and give you options for dual boot. when you choose the primary drive from boot menu it acts as single boot untill the grub update occurs in primary drive..

Comment: Also, in addition to the above comment, do not run `update-grub` on the primary 1st drive or it will pick up the other drives and add them to the existing grub.

Comment: The comment is more a full fledged answer. If you add it as an answer I can flag it as the answer. in addition, could you provide more details about the steps you specified? For example, When are where specifically do I create the EFI system partition, and when and where do I choose "bootloaded for installation".

Comment: the installation procedure is just as you install ubuntu in uefi mode on single harddrive as a single boot. choose it from something elase screen the EFI and bootloader.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1045035/739431 just for reference..

Comment: Your fears are justified since the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode ignores the dropdown for the location of the bootloader -- see bugs  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457 and add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list.  Various post install fixes are discussed in the bugs.

Comment: If you remove the first drive when installing to the second drive it can't be affected. Once Linux is installed on the second drive plug in the first drive, boot it and run sudo update-grub. The second drive will be added to the first drives boot menu.

Comment: Cs cameron. That is the best answer. can you add it as an answer?